# OcotberCMS PivotModel $attachOne relation

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yaml, relationship, octobercms

I am trying to create `many-to-many` relation with a file attachment pivot in `OcotberCMS`.

Here's my relation

```
public $belongsToMany = [
    'users' => [
        User::class,
        'key' => 'task_id',
        'otherKey' => 'user_id',
        'table' => 'tasks_users',
        'pivot' => ['status'],
        'pivotModel' => TaskUser::class
    ]
];
```

In my pivotModel

```
class TaskUser extends Pivot
...
public $attachOne = [
    'file' => ['System\Models\File']
];
```

YAML config

```
pivot:
    form:
        tabs:
            fields:
                pivot[file]:
                    label: Image
                    type: fileupload
                    mode: image
                    span: left
                    tab: Image
```

The form is rendered correctly, but when trying to upload the file, the error is thrown:
`Upload error "A widget with class name 'relationUsersManagePivotFormPivotFile' has not been bound to the controller" on line 605 of D:\Projects\esport\modules\backend\classes\Controller.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's kind of a lot of nesting which the relation manager is not able to handle. As well `File` does not work with `differed binding` when in used in pivot modal.

> Relation manager with `differed binding` pivot data is not supported
> Ref: https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#belongs-to-many-pivot

So maybe we can use an alternate way. if that is possible.

1. In pivot table you can add new field `file` with `text type`
2. Specify it in relation config => `'pivot' => ['status', 'file']`

And now from the field

```
pivot:
    form:
        fields:
            pivot[value]:
                label: Value
                type: text
            pivot[file]:
                label: Picture
                type: mediafinder
```

> Now you can upload and select files or select existing files. they will be stored as `file path` so they can directly be accessed.

if any doubt please comment.